# xfce terminal ignores set default shell

Tags: shell, terminal, xfce, manjaro, fish

I changed the default shell with

```
chsh -s `which fish`
```

but my terminal still launches with bash. If I run chsh again, it says `chsh: Shell not changed.` I'm using Manjaro x86_64 20.2.1 with XFCE (4.16). This is a mainly clean install (like 4 days old), only really having neofetch, and fish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem by rebooting. *I feel silly now*

Comment: `chsh` changes the system database immediately, but running processes only check it when they start, so logging out and in again (or rebooting) is required!